# datarepeater like control in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I need some kind of control to wrap my UI (which generates using binding). Currently I use ListBox but not sure if it's lightest or best choice. I just need placeholder that I can bind to and insert my controls.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably looking for the [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes, this is what I needed. Here is article discussing it exactly as I needed: http://wildermuth.com/2009/01/18/Fun_with_ItemsControl

Comment: I've found out that Telerik's ItemsControl has ItemTemplateSelector property, pretty useful if you have access to telerik's controls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any control that takes a list of entities as it's data source.

This could be `DataGrid`, `ListBox` (as you are already using) or anything that inherits from [`ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) - this includes things like the `TabControl` as well.